# Hexadecimal output is always garbled

Tags: python, hex

Why hex output will be garbled？

```py
message = b'\x34\x3F\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x01\x10\x00\x05\x00\x01\x02\xff\xff'

print(message)
```

output:

```py
b'4?\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x01\x10\x00\x05\x00\x01\x02\xff\xff'
```

Comment: What are you considering garbled? If a character can be displayed instead of an escape sequence, then that character will be used... eg: `4?` is still `\x34\x3f` - if you want something else than that - you have to be explicit in formatting it.

Answer (score 0):

Based from what I can tell it seems to get changed from your assignment:

```
>>> message = b'\x34\x3F\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x01\x10\x00\x05\x00\x01\x02\xff\xff'
>>> message
b'4?\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x01\x10\x00\x05\x00\x01\x02\xff\xff'
```

What you can do instead is just treat it as a raw string rather than converting it, that is if you just need it as a string:

```
>>> message = r'\x34\x3F\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x01\x10\x00\x05\x00\x01\x02\xff\xff'
>>> print(message)
\x34\x3F\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x01\x10\x00\x05\x00\x01\x02\xff\xff
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In fact, ‘message’ is the data I received. Is there a way to convert it to string and output it correctly?